# Bootstrap multiple root modules each with different providers (provided from outside)

Tags: angular

My application is not a SPA but I use Angular 2 for some parts of the page. I have created multiple root modules that I bootstrap with injectable providers which contain informations from the outside world:

Root module 1:

```
let serviceOne = new ServiceOne("SuperImportantInfoFromSomewhere");
let providers: any = [{ provide: ServiceOne, useValue: serviceOne }];
platformBrowserDynamic(MyFirstRootModule, providers);
```

Root module 2, somewhere at the bottom of the page:

```
let serviceTwo = new ServiceTwo(42);
let providers: any = [{ provide: ServiceTwo, useValue: serviceTwo }];
platformBrowserDynamic(MySecondRootModule, providers);
```

Sadly, this does not work. When I want `ServiceTwo` to get injected into a component, it fails. It only works if I provide both services at the first bootstrap (in this case `MyFirstRootModule`). It must be something related to the new DI system I don't fully understand.

Since I work within a CMS I do not know all providers at the first bootstrap; the two modules do not even know each other.

Is there a way to completely separate those two modules or somehow provide the second service to the DI system after the first root module has been bootstraped?

Comment: The thing that matters is what are bootstrap components for both. It doesn't look like a good use case for Angular 2 after all.

Comment: You are right, they left some use cases behind on their way to 2.0. Sad.

Comment: There may be better alternatives to your approach. If root component for the second module is a child of root component for the first one, this is the actual problem. Please, explain your case in details, [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a very dirty workaround. Before bootstraping the module I add the provider directly to the annotations of the class using the Reflect API:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { MySecondRootModule } from "MySecondRootModule";
import { ServiceTwo } from "ServiceTwo";

export class MySecondRootApplication
{
    constructor()
    {
        let serviceTwo = new ServiceTwo(42);
        let annotations: Array<any> = (Reflect as any).getMetadata("annotations", MySecondRootModule);      

        if (annotations[0].providers != undefined)
        {
            annotations[0].providers.push({ provide: ServiceTwo, useValue: serviceTwo });
        }
        else
        {
            annotations[0].providers = [{ provide: ServiceTwo, useValue: serviceTwo }];
        }

        (Reflect as any).defineMetadata("annotations", annotations, type);

        // Perform what ever else needs to be done

        platformBrowserDynamic(MySecondRootModule);
    }
}
```

I know, it's bad. But it works. By the way: Using this method also provides the ability to alter the templateUrl, for example if you want to use an ASP.NET MVC partial view result.